# show and hide based on drop down list asp mvc 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning asp.net mvc 5.

My `dropdownlistfor` is working perfect and shows right field based on its value.
But the problem is when the page loaded first time it shows all field..

**Problem is: I want default is showing nothing when the page first time loaded.**

my cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PaymentMethod, ViewBag.PayTypeList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle", @id = "PaymentId" })
                        <div id="PaypalButton">
                            <br/>
                            <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/button.js?"
                                    data-merchant="braintree"
                                    data-id="paypal-button"
                                    data-button="checkout"
                                    data-color="gold"
                                    data-size="medium"
                                    data-shape="pill"
                                    data-button_disabled="true">
                            </script>
                            <!--data-button_type="paypal_submit"-->
                        </div>
                        <div id="EcheckForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VecInsNum, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Vehicle Isurance Number", required = "required", tabindex = 18 })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VecInsNum, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And Js:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PaymentId').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == '1') {
                $('#PaypalButton').show();
                $('#EcheckForm').hide();
            } else if (value == '2') {
                $('#PaypalButton').hide();
                $('#EcheckForm').show();
            } else {
                $('#PaypalButton').hide();
                $('#EcheckForm').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

**When the page first time loaded:**
[image]

**When I select Paypal:**
[image]

**when I select E-check:**
[image]

**When I go back to Default:**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create a function which contains hide methods inside it:

```
// hide all div options
function hideOnLoad() {
    $('#PaypalButton').hide();
    $('#EcheckForm').hide();
}
```

Then, call function above to hide all option `div` elements when page has loaded at first time and when default value being selected as given below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    hideOnLoad(); // add this line
    $('#PaymentId').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '1') {
            $('#PaypalButton').show();
            $('#EcheckForm').hide();
        } else if (value == '2') {
            $('#PaypalButton').hide();
            $('#EcheckForm').show();
        } else {
            hideOnLoad();
        }
    });
});
```

Simplified example: [JSFiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/5qk0n1Lu/1/)